# How can I see where the players are clicking in spectator mode and in replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

When I am spectator or in replays, I can switch vision to just one player so I will see where he or she moves his vision focus and I can see what the player is selecting in the bottom interface section.

But how can I see where the player is clicking?

I think in some youtube replays, there is visible which points they click and which waypoints are set to units.

Can I activate that information somewhere, maybe with an external review extension program?

Comment: I vote to close because of the changing of the questions. It appears you don't know what you want to ask and therefore we can't help you.

Comment: @YoungGuilo The question...wasn't changed.  It was expanded to include replays, as well as spectator mode.  Seems like a valid thing to do, since you're just watching both modes, one live, the other after the fact.

Comment: It is pretty clear: I want to see the clicks of the players. it doesent matter if in spectator mode or replay mode (which seems to be quite similar to me). This should be of big interest to many players, cause it is not easy to find such an option (in any mode) I hope you can help me explain, where to find it

Comment: @rubo77 Spectating is NOT the same as watching a replay. You need to be clear in your question the then.

Answer (score 2):

You can't see the actual clicks that the players do.

But if you choose to have vision from one player instead of both/all of them, then you can see which unit or building he or she currently has selected.

EDIT: 
If you watch a replay, select the player you want to observe clicks from.

Comment: Ok, you can see that in the bottom interface. But in the videos of replays I always see small circles that indicate that the player clicked there. And I see paths of units, if they have any

Comment: @rubo77 Yes in a replay. Your question is based on spectating a match.

Comment: 2 downvotes for a correct answer. I dont get it sometimes :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it is not correct. I heard, in youtube, you can see replays with the points clicked in the game too

Comment: @rubo77 You question is about seeing clicks in a specatating mode (eg. live action) not replay. I have not said that its not possible in a replay :) I have only confirmed you that it is possible in a replay.

Comment: I edited the question. I would be happy if i knew how to activate that in a replay

Comment: @rubo77 now you're asking a different question.

Comment: not really, i am looking, how to activate the clicks. how can i see what the players are/were doing?

Comment: @rubo77 You are specificly asking about how to see the clicks in spectator mode. You need to be specific in your question. You ask one thing, and expect a total different thing. Then you edit your question a lot later, making it even harder to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can't see where people click in Starcraft. Like you said you can only see the player's movements.

Comment: So when I see replays on youtube where you see the points, where they click, these are just live captured videos?

Comment: Is this only possible in replays and not as spectator? Or how does Husky make theis visible then in his vidoes? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ocq-FxskxeA&feature=share&list=UUZ8D7Qvm0YHm0vZKFl-AFdA

Comment: @rubo77 no they are only available in replays and live videos.

Comment: ok, so how can I activate them in  a replay? I didn't find the option

Comment: @rubo77 you can only see what he selected not the actual mouse.